# What was funny about Hanzo's hand in the film Predators?

Tags: plot-explanation, predator

In the 2010 film *[Predators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predators_(film))*, the Yakuza character Hanzo (played by Louis Ozawa Changchien) and Edwin (played by Topher Grace) are having a conversation about how Hanzo can speak English and why he does not speak English more often.

Hanzo retorts that he would talk too much and then shows his hand which is missing 2 fingers.

They then both start laughing, why is that funny or what was the joke?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It was possibly a joke about Hanzo's too much talking.

When Edwin notices Hanzo can speak English he asks him why he doesn't talk more. He then shows his hand that is missing 2 fingers.

**In the Yakuza when a member talks against a gang leader or speaks out of turn, a finger joint is cut off.**

Those 2 missing fingers just indicates that how much Hanzo used to talk and why he doesn't talk much like before.